# VideoLan VLC player ActiveX

Tags: delphi, vlc

Based on [this example](http://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX/Delphi) I have imported the VLC ActiveX.

When I try to put VLCPlugin on my form (or when I create it at run-time) I get an error message:

```
The specified procedure could not be found. (EOleSysError)
4001a321 +019 Vcl50.bpl    Comobj   OleError
4001a334 +010 Vcl50.bpl    Comobj   OleCheck
400d1c15 +0e9 Vcl50.bpl    Olectrls TOleControl.CreateInstance
400d1155 +125 Vcl50.bpl    Olectrls TOleControl.Create
```

Tested in D5/7 with VLC player 0.9.8a

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Make sure you include ActiveX unit in your uses clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution for using the ActiveX component, but the Australian Delphi User Group [published links to native headers](http://members.adug.org.au/2011/12/19/delphi-headers-now-available-for-vlc/).

You also might want to upgrade your VLC to the latest version (1.1.11).